# How to make an Android widget that runs a certain piece of code?

Tags: java, android, widget, icons

I was wondering how to make a simple widget with just an icon that runs something that I have in my full app. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. I'm not going to post any code here, because a widget requires quite a bit of code. It's best to go through the tutorial here  - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html.

Basically what you want to do is create a widget with a button. In the onClick of that button, start an intent, or send a Broadcast that your app will handle, which then runs the code (in a background thread).